# Is there an Autofixture attribute that can be used instead of fixture.Inject() in the code?

Tags: entity-framework, moq, xunit, autofixture

I am creating tests against an Entity Framework 6 repository.  Due to a dependency between a product type and loan, I get a circular reference error when using Autofixture.AutoMoq.  Is there an attribute that I can place over a test method so I can eliminate the following line of code (and its related items in the example, below): `"fixture.Inject(Enumerable.Empty<Loan>());"`

I am using XUnit 2.1.0.3179, Autofixture 3.50.2.0, Autofixutre.AutoMoq 3.50.2.0,  AutoFixture.Xnit2, Moq 4.5.29.0

Here are some additional details, which may be helpful...

Loan(N) --- (1) ProductType

Due to the circular reference in my EF6 model, I cannot do the following:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void ProductTypes_GetList()
    List<ProductType> productTypeList,
    [Frozen] Mock<IProductTypeRepository> productTypeRepo)
{
```

Instead, I have to do the following in order to avoid the circular reference issue:

```
   var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    // Avoid circular dependency in EF.  
    // Eliminating the many side of the relationship.
    fixture.Inject(Enumerable.Empty<Loan>());

    var productTypeRepo = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IProductTypeRepository>>();

    // Create a list of product types.
    List<ProductType> productTypeList = fixture.Create<List<ProductType>>();

    productTypeRepo.Setup(_ => _.GetAll()).Returns(productTypeList);
```

I would appreciate learning whether it is possible to achieve my goal and reduce the lines of code.

Thank you in advance for time and suggestions.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use customization to do this, and wrap your own customization into an attribute..

Heres an example of a customization:

```
fixture.Customize<ProductType>(x => x.Without(y => y.ProductTypes));
```

You can wrap customizations up into a class that implements `ICustomization` and finally following the guidance in [Encapsulating AutoFixture Customizations](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations/) by Mark Seemann, you can wrap that all up nicely into an attribute so you can do:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData, MyCustomizations]
public void ProductTypes_GetList()
```